# Regex Expression using OR and single occurrence

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which satisfies the following conditions.

1. Should start with a alpha-numeric character
2. Special characters allowed are `-` `'` and space
3. Special characters cannot be at the start or end of the string
4. Special characters cannot occur side by side.
5. Length of string is 20 characters
6. Minimum length is 1 character

I am using following regex but missing the fourth point:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9] ([-|'] * [a-zA-Z0-9])*${0,20}
```

Comment: What is the minimum length of the string?

Comment: The max length is given as 20 and no constraint mentioned on minimum length. We can start from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*?['-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9'-]{0,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

This assumes that minimum length of string is 2 and max length is 20.

`(?!.*?['-]{2})` is **negative lookahead** that makes sure there no case of 2 consecutive special characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Can u explain the negative lookahead expression. It will be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: [See this very good tutorial on lookarounds in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Hi, How to ensure that the minimum length of the string in the above expression is "1".  I tried different ways but not successful.

Comment: But minimum length is already 3 in above regex. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: I have a scenario for a name where the minimum length should be 1 and other conditions should also hold good. The above expression works when minimum length is 2. I tried modifying the above expression but didnot get the expected result..

Comment: ok then use: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?!.*?['-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9'-]{0,18}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`